# expected expression on javascript function

Tags: javascript, vb.net, inline-code

I am using this function to display map using virtual map .  when i run this i get exception about the expression expected on `<% if (b == 0) Then %>` what i am doing wrong 
Below is my javascript code 
i declared `Dim b As Integer`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&amp;s=1&amp;mkt=en-us"></script>`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var myMap = null;

         function LoadMap()
         {
            myMap = new VEMap("mapDiv");
            myMap.LoadMap();
            myMap.SetZoomLevel(1);

<% If RS.HasRows Then %>
<% if (b == 0) Then %>
 StartGeocoding<%=b %>("<%= rs("lot_address") & " " & rs ("lot_city") %>, <%= rs("lot_state") & " " & rs("lot_zip")%>");
<% end if%>
function StartGeocoding<%=b%> ( address )
{
   myMap.Find(null,    // what
              address, // where
              null,    // VEFindType (always VEFindType.Businesses)
              null,    // VEShapeLayer (base by default)
              null,    // start index for results (0 by default)
              null,    // max number of results (default is 10)
              null,    // show results? (default is true)
              null,    // create pushpin for what results? (ignored since what is null)
              null,    // use default disambiguation? (default is true)
<%if(b==0) Then %>
              null,    // set best map view? (default is true)
<%else%>
              false,    // set best map view? (default is true)
<%end if%>
              GeocodeCallback<%= b %>);  // call back function
}

function GeocodeCallback<% =b %> (shapeLayer, findResults, places, moreResults, errorMsg)
{
   // if there are no results, display any error message and return
   if(places == null)
   {
      alert( (errorMsg == null) ? "There were no results" : errorMsg );
      return;
   }

   var bestPlace = places[0];

   // Add pushpin to the *best* place
   var location = bestPlace.LatLong;
   var newShape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, location);

   var desc = "<%=rs("lot_address")%><br /><%=rs("lot_city")%>, <%=rs("lot_state")&" "&rs("lot_zip")%><br /><br /><a href='lot.asp?id=<%=rs("id")%>' class='link' style='color:black;'><strong>&raquo; Get More Details & Rates</strong></a>";
   newShape.SetDescription(desc);
   newShape.SetTitle("<%=rs("lot_name")%>");
   myMap.HideInfoBox();
   myMap.AddShape(newShape);
   myMap.HideInfoBox();
   <%rs.movenext
   if RS.HasRows Then 
   if (b==1) then%>
    myMap.ZoomOut();
  <%end if%>
    StartGeocoding<%=b+1%>("<%=rs("lot_address")&" "&rs("lot_city")%>, <%=rs("lot_state")&" "&rs("lot_zip")%>");
   <%else
   %>
   myMap.ZoomOut();
   <%end if
  // rs.moveprevious :
   %>
   myMap.HideInfoBox();
}

<%
b=b+1

rs.read
loop
rs.
%>
   myMap.HideInfoBox();
         }

         function UnloadMap()
         {
            if (myMap != null) {
               myMap.Dispose();
            }
         }
    </script>
```

Comment: how about `<% if b = 0 Then %>`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line (*plus other lines written in similar syntax*) :

```
<% if (b==0) Then %>
```

to this :

```
<% If b = 0 Then %>
```

It seems like you mixed VB.NET syntax with javascript in the same code block. That part inside `<% %>` should be written in VB.NET only, just be more careful.

Comment: any other problem, or this solution fixed expression expected error you got? please accept this answer if it solved your problem